# Play MP3 audio in VB.Net (.NET2.0/Mono/.NET Compact 3.5)

Tags: .net, vb.net, mono

I'm trying to find the best way to play an MP3 file in VB.Net under.NET2.0. I will also need to support .NET Compact 3.5 and probably Mono. I've tried NAudio which I can get to work in .NET2.0 (sort of) and I suspect it may work in .NET Compact too.

Anyone have any suggestions about other ways I might achieve this? Specifically, i'm looking to join together several MP3 files into a MemoryStream and play them without writing to disk.
I've done the joining bit, its the playing of the MemoryStream that i'm looking for help on.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: By the fact that you mention Compact Framework I assume you need to target Windows Mobile devices. AFAIK there's no library that will work cross-platform for you - you'll need to P/Invoke one on the desktop side and dig into WinMobile API on the embedded device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote an MP3 decoder and player, completely in VB.NET and its only dependency is [SlimDX](http://slimdx.org/), which is used as wrapper for DirectSound.

The decoder, decodes the MP3 files and writes the uncompressed audio stream into a DirectSound buffer for playback. Also, the decoder is compiled as a DLL so that it can be easily reused on any number of projects.

You can download the source code from this blog post: [vbNetMP3Player](http://whenimbored.xfx.net/2011/01/an-mp3-decoder-written-in-vb/)

The project targets .NET 4.0 but it will run just fine for .NET 3.5, and probably, .NET 2.0
As for Mono support, I haven't tested it, but I don't see why it shouldn't work.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks xfx. I'm going to stick with NAudio but the SlimDX approach would seem like a good alternative.

Answer (score 1):

[GStreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/) is good option, it's a cross platform multimedia framework. And there are bindings that would meet your needs: access the information you require (length of a video file) via a .NET API: [GStreamerSharp](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer-sharp/).

Indeed, we actually use it in the [Banshee Project](http://banshee.fm/), a media player written in C# (which was the default music player bundled in Ubuntu about a year and a half ago).

BTW, GStreamer is architected in a way that codecs are plugins, so you have an abstraction between the internals of them (i.e. ffmpeg) which other plugins could fulfill depending on your licensing/format needs.

Answer (score 0):

I was having same problem and looked for many alternatives. Then I found BASS. It is very easy to use yet you can do pretty much anything. Also its .NET wrapper called BASS .NET contains a very nice documentation and examples for each function for VB and C#. They also have a very active and supportive forum. I once found a bug and reported on forum, then they gave me fixed version in just one day...

[Link for BASS](http://www.un4seen.com/bass.html) and [.NET wrapper](http://www.un4seen.com/download.php?z/4/Bass24.Net.zip)

[Projects that are using BASS](http://www.un4seen.com/bass_showcase.php)

[Documentation example](http://www.bass.radio42.com/help/html/e49e005c-52c0-fc33-e5f9-f27f2e0b1c1f.htm)

Comment: I have used BASS extensively and I agree that is a wonderful audio library. But it is important to note that is only free for non-commercial use.

Comment: Yep. I checked out BASS and discarded it based upon the licensing. Thanks for the heads up though.